# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat DATE_ATOM ISO 8601

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601

I am using `PHP 7.2`, and trying to create a date from a string as follows:

```
$dateString = '2018-12-31T01:01:01+00:00';
$converted  = DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_ATOM), $dateString);
```

The snippet above works fine and returns the expected result.

The problem happens when I swap the day and month in the date string provided above, as follows:

```
$dateString = '2018-31-12T01:01:01+00:00';
$converted  = DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_ATOM), $dateString);
```

I was expecting this second example to return `false`, but instead I get an actual date time, `2020-07-12 01:01:01.000000`.

So, I have no way of telling whether the second date was a proper date or not, because the system accepted it, and I will be saving in my database something which I shouldn't.

Could this be considered a bug in `PHP 7.2`?

Comment: Noway... you can set the format for your datetime something like this
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

Comment: Can you use [checkdate()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) to check the date beforehand?

Comment: I have an irresistible urge to validate data input from an unknown source, @billyonecan

Comment: What would I achieve with that, @BILALMALIK?

Comment: I can @kerbholz, but with the result returned from `DateTime::createFromFormat` is an actual valid date, albeit not the one I expected. I would prefer the system to throw `false`, because with ISO 8601 in mind, there is no such 31 month.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you need to know which data represents the month, and which represents the day, otherwise how would you know one from the other when the current day is <= 12

Comment: It should be possible @billyonecan, because with ISO 8601, the second component should be the month.

Comment: I mean check the date before you `DateTime::createFromFormat` it. `checkdate(31,12,2018)` should return false. If so, don't convert it.

Comment: @Nicolas yes - with both atom and iso8601 the second component is the month, but you're passing this as the day. You're telling php to create a date with a specific format and then providing it incorrectly

Comment: @billyonecan, well that's the point. I am receiving that value from an unknown source, and I want to check it is in the expected format... and since it does not, I should be able to return an error to the client application (e.g. 'unknown date format'). Instead, I get an actual date, which I would assume it is correct because the system parsed it without errors.

Comment: So what happens if somebody chooses 8 for the month and 9 for the day. That's a valid date, but it's wrong because the format you've told PHP to create the date from isn't the same as the string you provide. It's not possible

Comment: @kerbholz, yes I could, but I am receiving the date as an string, and to implement your proposal, I have to parse the date myself to extract those values.

Comment: @billyonecan, yes, you are correct, but that is beyond the scope of the validator I want to implement. But I should be able to tell apart dates having a month outside range.

Comment: Then you'd need to use something like `checkdate()` as suggested. PHP is trying to compensate for your error. It sees the month 31 but knows that it can't be > 12, so it adds 19 (31 - 12) months to the date you've provided

Comment: Not really @billyonecan. I receive that date as a string (as part of a payload sent to an API endpoint), and in order to implement that approach, I have to parse the date myself, which I shouldn't be doing because the endpoint requires that date to be in ISO8601 format.

Comment: Hm, something like https://3v4l.org/Ja2RM ?? Or am I not getting it?

Comment: Yeah @kerbholz, that seems to do the job, which is strange because `date_create_from_format` is just the procedural style of the object oriented style `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Comment: It's not strange, it's using `checkdate()`

Comment: @billyonecan, yeah, but that extra logic shouldn't be needed. It is a nice workaround, but the original question is still unanswered.

Comment: Don't specify the format (since you don't know what it will be anyway) when creating the DateTime object. It'll [throw an exception if it can't parse the date](https://3v4l.org/gPsrS)

Comment: @billyonecan, I just want to enforce the client to sent the payload in the format I expect, and to return bad request otherwise. I'd rather not guess what the client is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

> Could this be considered a bug in PHP 7.2?

No, this is how the method is intentionally implemented. You can argue if it's the *right* way to implement it, but that's how it *is*. Notably even if we all agree that it's not right here, it will still keep working as it's implemented.

The practical answer here is to write a validator (for entirety of format and all parts) and run any untrusted input through it.

Comment: I still don't think that is the intended behavior of the function. If the function was instructed to parse a date as `DATE_ATOM` (or any other format for that matter), and the value is not in that format, it should return `false` rather than trying to parse the date and return junk data.